# How integers are displayed in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-3

I have tables where the primary ID field is an integer that starts at 2 000 000. This number is allocated as the next available number - entered manually or calculated from the last available number. The progress of the count (above 2 000 000) is spread across multiple tables so they are not necessarily in sequence in any particular table.

In QGIS v3.0, when I look at that ID in the table view, the integer is truncated and presented the way Excel does when the number is too large. So 2048273 shows as 2.04827+06. I can double click in the field to see the actual ID, but that is a nuisance. I want to be able to see the ID without having to click.

How can I do that? Or is this similar to the other question about the American format and was fixed in a later version?

Comment: What is the data source of your 'table'?

Comment: [Bug in QGIS3.0 ?](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18508)

Comment: @DPSSpatial - I don't understand your question. The tables are not 'from' anywhere. They live on an MS SQL server and I add to them every day. I have only recently started to use QGIS 3. I didn't have this problem in any previous version (going back to 2.12)

Comment: @Johanna the source of your table is then MS SQL Server, rather than an Excel file or Shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to QGIS 3.2, it has been available for 2 months and this bug (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18508) is fixed in it.

Comment: I was able to get to a machine with 3.2 installed and can confirm that it is no longer an issue. Thank you to all who helped.